# VHDL entity and architecture design

Tags: vhdl

With Ada I can split my modular units into specification and body with .ads and .adb files.

Is it possible to separate VHDL entity and architecture? If so, is there a naming convention or recommended style for doing this?  And can the entities be placed in a custom library/package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Libraries

*Everything* gets compiled into a library.  By default this is called "work", but you can override this.  I rarely have to use that though - it's occasionally useful with external IP if there are namespace clashes.  As Chiggs commented, using libraries to create namespaces is a good practice.  Most synthesizers [can deal with multiple libraries now](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14335/which-synthesis-tools-support-vhdl-libraries/14628#14628), although it wasn't always the case.  All the simulators can (as far as I know).  There's also a bit more hassle involved in setting them up (you have to tell the compiler where they all are).

---

maybe an example - say you have an i2c controller and an spi controller.  You could call both blocks `controller` and compile them into their own libraries called `i2c` and `spi` and then instantiate them like this:

```
i2c_instance:entity i2c.controller...etc
spi_instance:entity spi.controller...etc
```

or you could call them `i2c_controller` and `spi_controller` and do:

```
i2c_instance:entity work.i2c_controller...etc
spi_instance:entity work.spi_controller...etc
```

---

And libraries are not "just the same" as hard disk folders. They are managed by the VHDL compiler, so you create and map them using whatever syntax the tool uses.

For example with Modelsim, `vlib` creates a library at a particular place in the filesystem (so it does look like a folder at this point) and `vmap` tells the compiler how to map a `use some_lib;` clause to a particular bit of the filesystem.

### Entities, architectures, packages

You can separate your entity and architecture (or even more than one architecture per entity) into multiple files, or keep them in one file.  Keeping the `architecture` in a separate file means that when you recompile it, you don't recompile the `entity`, which means you don't have to recompile everything that instantiates it.

Similarly with `packages` and `package body`s - bodies in a separate file means you can just recompile that part without recompiling everything else.  Note that `package`s are not for putting entities in.

(Aside - Modelsim has a `-just` switch that allows you to keep everything in one file and just compile selected bits of the files, for example, just the `architecture` and/or `body` part(s))

### Summary

- Compile re-useable cores into their own library to protect their namespace
- Compile everything else into the `work` library
- Put useful constants, functions, procedures, type definitions into one or more packages
- Putting entities and architectures into one or more files is a matter of taste and development style more than anything else
- Putting packages and package bodies into one or more files is a matter of taste and development style more than anything else

Comment: _Compile everything into the work library (unless you have good reason not to)_

Have to disagree with this statement - failure to make use of namespaces (good practice) will only come back and bite you when the design grows or you want to reuse some modules. I would advise compiling everything into appropriately named libraries and using direct entity instantiation:

`library i2c;

i_i2c_controller : entity i2c.controller
`

Comment: @Chiggs There's a potential good reason not to then :)  I've never had to and I've reused a whole bunch of code. Synth tools support of non-work libraries can be spotty, which is why I've avoided it in the past.  I'll update the answer...

Comment: I think the popular toolchains [are happy with libraries](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14335/which-synthesis-tools-support-vhdl-libraries/14628#14628) - after all, it's only _18 years_ since they were introduced to VHDL! Ada95 introduced hierarchical library support which I'm hoping will [make it into VHDL](http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/CollectedRequirements)

Comment: I know XST hasn't been in the past (not sure about now) - But I agree, they *should* be :)  I like your proposals for hierarchy and renaming too!

Comment: A discussion on the merits of libraries: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t522692-use-of-libraries.html

Answer (score 5):

Entity and architecture are separate *design units*. They can be in the same file or they can be in separate files. The file extensions remain the same: usually `.vhd` but `.vhdl` is also possible. For the file names, there is no generally accepted naming convention. (There are hundreds of conventions really, so that is as useful as no convention at all) Anything works; as an example, you could use `myEntity.vhd` and `myEntity_RTL.vhd`.

You can compile entities and architectures that you write in your own library. You might use your company name as library name.

Don't confuse **libraries** with **packages**, though! A package is a compilation unit that holds reusable declarations. A library is a named set of compilation units.

Comment: So a package is just for data types functions?  And a library is for entities and architectures?  For example, with Modelsim I can create a new library, which essentially is just a directory on the hard disk.  If I have my VHDL source code inside that directory, is it automatically included in the library?  Do I have to write some sort of library specification?

Comment: Libraries do not necessarily correspond to folders on your disk. Libraries contain entities, architectures, packages, package bodies and/or configurations. You tell ModelSim in which library a given file goes on the command line: `vcom -work myLibrary myFile.vhd`