# What is the recommended way for carrying VHDL code around?

Tags: vhdl, code-organization

I have a VHDL design consisting of a few entities and a package. The entities use some definitions from the package, and may use each other as components.

Let's say I created it with one tool, but after some time I'd like to take that code and use it in another tool.

What is the "right way" to carry VHDL design around this way? Should I make a library from it? (And can I later "import" that library to other tools than it was created with?) What I'd like to achieve is something like Java package, that can be easily handled and included in different projects. Is there a way to "replicate" that in VHDL?

I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087868/vhdl-entity-and-architecture-design) and it confused me somehow. Should I just keep my entities and architectures in "work" and just move the package to library?

Comment: VHDL source code is portable between VHDL tool implementations. When a design unit is successfully analyzed it is stored in a library, by default what ever work is, in context. Library formats are implementation defined and are not portable.

Comment: Alright, so basically carry single files around?

Comment: Yes,  carry the files around. "A <i>design library</i> is an implementation-dependent storage facility for previously analyzed design units. A given implementation is required to support any number of design libraries. " IEEE Std 1076-2008, 13.2 Design libraries.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VHDL source code is generally portable between VHDL tool implementations.

When a design unit is successfully analyzed it is stored in a library, by default what ever work is, in context.

Library formats are implementation defined and are not portable.

IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.2 Design libraries, para 1:

> A *design library* is an implementation-dependent storage facility for previously analyzed design units. A given implementation is required to support any number of design libraries.

and para 6:

> For a given library logical name, the actual name of the corresponding design library in the host environment may or may not be the same. A given implementation shall provide some mechanism to associate a library logical name with a host-dependent library. Such a mechanism is not defined by the language.

There's nothing stopping you from moving designs as a collection of design files (source code) between tool implementations within the bounds of portability issues. That includes source code for any library a particular design unit depends on.

The  STD and IEEE libraries are required to be supported as are their various packages (STANDARD, std_logic_1164, numeric_std, numeric_bit,...) providing a framework for portability within the limitations found in Annex D, Potentially nonportable constructs.